# How to remove extra column (with no header) in csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv, parsing

I got a csv file that in 1 (or more) row I have an extra value, that doesnt match the first line header

Example:

```
name,age,gender
abc,20,m
def,28,f
ghi,36,f
jkl,23,f,a
xyz,30,m
```

I want to load this dataset in a Pandas Dataframe, so how can I remove this value using Python?
Because of the size of the original file, regular text/sheet tools won't load all lines

- Got this error while loading into pandas

`df = pd.read_csv(data,delimiter=',')`

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 166 fields in line 26398, saw 167

Comment: Show what you have tried? Where it went wrong? What are your inputs/expected output? Use a full error traceback.

Comment: How are you getting this error? `df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')` works fine just copying the shown csv into `test.csv`. I get columns: `Index(['name', 'age', 'gender', 'Unnamed: 3'], dtype='object')` with no erros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample csv

```
name,age,gender
abc,20,m
def,28,f
ghi,36,f
jkl,23,f,a
xyz,30,m
```

python code - use [`usecols` argument of `pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', usecols=[0, 1, 2]) # or usecols=['name', 'age', 'gender']
print(df)
```

output

```
  name  age gender
0  abc   20      m
1  def   28      f
2  ghi   36      f
3  jkl   23      f
4  xyz   30      m
```